# Create an activity that has a webView in it

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android app just for fun and practice.
The app consists of a splash screen and 4 activities.

One of the activites is filled with a webView.

I'm not able to get that webView work, when I run the app it shows only a white background.

here is my code :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oXHzBauNDy68mEIyI5EeNooIc9GaVPFh

Sorry to link the code in google drive, I wasn't able to properly format the question.

Any help will be appreciated

btw :  activity_livechat is not a launcher activity.

Comment: How much code are you adding? In the question editing window, press spacebar four times to turn a line of text into a formatted code block. Once you figure that out, narrow down exactly what lines of code are giving you the trouble, don't just dump an entire project on StackOverflow. Also, it's probably not the best idea to give out a link to your Google Drive.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: please post the relevant parts of code here

Comment: the code is a lot and some of the code is not appearing, if I go line by line adding 4 spaces when I try to posts it says that it appears that you didn't format the code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, enable JavaScript on your webview

```
Webview.getsettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Additionally, it's best to have error received methods in place for your webview so you'll know exactly what is the problem related to.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

@Override
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
       Toast.makeText(context, "this is my error: " + description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
       }
});
```

Comment: sorry to bother you but can you further explain more how to do this part :  "error received methods in place for your webview"

Comment: @Adnit You can bother me whenever you want if it's code related :) I've made the requested changes to the answer, please check